# compare strings in sh

Tags: shell-script, shell

Here is what I tried:

```
#! /bin/sh
    if [ -z "${ENCRYPT_ALL_PWD}" ]; then
        if [ ! -z $SA_USER ]; then
            DBAUSER=$SA_USER
            $ECHO "Yahoo!!!!!!!!!!!!"
         else
            $ECHO "Please define variable SA_USER in $HOME/<blah>profile and run this script again..."
            exit 1
         fi
    fi
```

But I am unable to get rid of the "not found" in the output when ENCRYPT_ALL_PWD is undefined:

```
$ sh -x swar_test.sh
+ [  != YES ]
+ [ ! -z ]
+ Please define variable SA_USER in <blah>/<blah>profile and run this script again...
swar_test.sh[7]: Please define variable SA_USER in <blah>/<blah>profile and run this script again...:  **not found**
+ exit 1
```

I have tried this as well, but it doesn't work either, and gives a "not found" when ENCRYPT_ALL_PWD is undefined/empty:

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ "${ENCRYPT_ALL_PWD}" != "YES" ]; then
    if [ ! -z $SA_USER ]; then
        DBAUSER=$SA_USER
        $ECHO "Yahoo!!!!!!!!!!!!"
     else
        $ECHO "Please define variable SA_USER in $HOME/<blah>profile and run this script again..."
        exit 1
     fi
fi
exit 0
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get rid of the "not found"?

My expectation is that when ENCRYPT_ALL_PWD is undefined/empty, and SA_USER is undefined as well, the output should be:

```
Please define variable SA_USER in $HOME/<blah>profile and run this script again...
```

Comment: What is the value of `$ECHO`?  My guess is it is undefined.

Comment: You are right. I was a total dunce not to see it before. There is an init file that sets ECHO: ECHO='/usr/bin/echo'. I had to import that.

Comment: or else use `${ECHO-echo}` this way undefind ECHO will fall back to shell's default.

Comment: @Rui -- please do not edit questions that are on hold unless you think that the edits make the question good enough to reopen. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller Been avoiding lately to edit new questions on hold, this one must have been a mistake. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

This set it right:

```
$ cat swar_test.sh
    #! /bin/sh

    . $HOME/tools/init.sh
    . $HOME/<blah>profile
    if [ "${ENCRYPT_ALL_PWD}" != "YES" ]; then
        if [ ! -z $SA_USER ]; then
            DBAUSER=$SA_USER
            $ECHO "Yahoo!!!!!!!!!!!!"
         else
            $ECHO "Please define variable SA_USER in $HOME/aaaprofile and run this script again..."
            exit 1
         fi
    fi
    exit 0
```